# bloom: Your track's 'actions' configuration is not the same as the default

Tags: ros, catkin, bloom-release, debian, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I go to release a package that I did not create (this is my first time releasing it) it says:

> Your track's 'actions' configuration is not the same as the default.
> Unless you have manually modified your 'actions' (the commands which get run for a release), you should update to the new default.
> Should it be updated to the default setting?

I'm pretty sure the answer is Yes, update to default. But how can I tell if the previous maintainer added a custom action?

I checked

http://bloom.readthedocs.org/en/0.5.7/search.html?q=action&check_keywords=yes&area=default

and

http://wiki.ros.org/bloom

and I could not find more documentation on this actions feature. I think more should be written about it.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192052/bloom:-your-track%27s-%27actions%27-configuration-is-not-the-same-as-the-default./) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2014-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer should almost definitely be Yes.

Changing the actions manually is possible, but not recommended. It would be up to people who change the actions to keep track of their diff from the default. So currently the best way to know if they modified the actions manually would be to look at the commit history of the `track.yaml` file and see if they manually changed it, or ask the other maintainer.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-09-05**:
"if they manually changed it" - all of the changes are made on their behalf by bloom - how can i tell when a user did something manually. perhaps bloom should in the future prepend "bloom: ..." to commit messages. see https://github.com/ros-gbp/random_numbers-release/commits/master/tracks.yaml

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-09-05**:
True, it would be better if bloom prefixed all commit messages with "bloom: ", and I do that in some cases, but at any rate I think you can see bloom's pattern there and that he did not modify it.